# Get author URL from Style.css using php (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, url, author

i have created a wordpress theme and now i want to show author url at the footer. How can i get it by php method from style .I know the simple method but to get it by mean of php just like WordPress gets Theme Name and Description from the comments in Style.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the following function for this:
 http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_theme

By default you can get the author info you need by using:

```
$theme_data = wp_get_theme();
$author_name = $theme_data->get( 'Author' );
```